# Waiting for user to lift mouse - not working: Love2D

Tags: lua, mouseevent, mouse, love2d

I'm busy creating a program using the Love2D engine, where the user clicks and it returns the co-ordinates of the mouse's current location. Before returning another location, however, the user has to 'un-click' the mouse and then click at the next desired location.

I've pasted the script that should handle this below:

```
function scripts.waitForMouseLift()
    while love.mouse.isDown("l", "r") do
        --Stays in a loop until user releases mouse, then lets the program continue
    end
end
```

This should technically work, since the loop would end when the mouse click is lifted, but instead it just carries on in an infinite loop, regardless of which mouse button I clicked before.

So, my question consists of two parts: firstly, is there a way of making this method work? Secondly, are there any alternatives or better solutions to this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: This procedure would be called when I need to wait for the user to 'un-click' before the program can continue. So it would essentially sit in that loop until the user 'un-clicks', at which point it will exit the loop and allow the rest of the program to continue running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Love uses callbacks for this and the one you're looking for is [`love.mousereleased`](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.mousereleased) and you might want to look at [`love.mousepressed`](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.mousepressed) too. These are functions you add to your script and whenever the user clicks (or releases) a mouse button the function is called. So you don't have to keep checking yourself to see if the mouse changed state and you can't wait for it in a busy loop since you need to give control back to Love so that it has a chance to update the mouse state.

```
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
  -- do something with x, y
  print("Mouse Pressed", button, "at", x, y)
end


function love.mousereleased(x, y, button)
  print("Mouse Released", button, "at", x, y)
end
```